# How to keep control with the browser while waiting for a jQuery AJAX load event?

Tags: jquery, ajax, multithreading

I have a web page with some local content/links and also two divs that load from long-running external API’s using jQuery.load().

I would like the user to be able to click away from the web page without waiting for the load events to complete. I believe my code is single-threaded and running in series, blocking the UI, so the user can't do anything on the page until both load()s are returned.

In my code below, you can click on the anchor tag, but it does not actually navigate away from the page until the load() events both complete in series. (It would be nice for the load() events to run in parallel also, and I think that is directly related to the first problem.)

How can I use jQuery to load the divs while still allowing the user to click within the rendered page before the load() events complete?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#div_test1").load("long1.aspx")
        $("#div_test2").load("long2.aspx")
    });
```

The web page:

```
<div>
    <p>Some content.</p>

    <p><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">click before load() completes</a></p>
    <p><a href="?">page reload</a></p>

    <div id="div_test1" style="border: 1px solid red; width: 100px;"></div>
    <div id="div_test2" style="border: 1px solid blue; width: 100px;"></div>
</div>
```

long1.aspx and long2.aspx just inject some time delay using VB.NET:

```
Private Sub long1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Response.CacheControl = "No-Cache"
    For counter = 1 To 10
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(400)
        Response.Write(String.Format("{0}<br />", counter.ToString))
    Next
End Sub
```

**EDIT:** 
I added a second href above, to simply reload the page. I now notice that external links, like www.stackoverflow.com, are NOT blocked, and will navigate as soon as the user clicks, without waiting for the load(). But any link to the same web site is blocked. You can click the link, but the browser won't go there until the load() is complete.

Comment: Not sure why calling `.load()` block UI? What is purpose of `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(400)`? _"(It would be nice for the load() events to run in parallel"_ The calls to `.load()` do appear to be called in parallel.

Comment: The Sleep function just simulates a long load() event. I tried adding a delay a few different ways, on the chance that something was happening because I was messing with the Thread, but the UI was still blocked. I agree that the load() events are initiated in parallel, but according to network inspector, they are running one after the other.

Comment: Why do you need to simulate a long `.load()` `$.ajax()` call?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind events to elements before the document is ready or the page is loaded. It will work the moment the document loads the code so you can put it in header and the rest in footer or somewhere else under it.

To bind an event:

```
$('.element').on('click',function(){
     //some code here
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but the click event is still blocked by the load(), until the load completes.